# Is there a preferable programming language for CGI apps?

Tags: c, perl, cgi

I know that I can write CGI in many languages, the most are C and Perl.
But why I have to write it in Perl or in C?
What's the difference and what's the (eventually) the best and safe solution?

Comment: Not really -  have a look here: http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5

Comment: Voting to close as "non-constructive": "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments" - see the [FAQ#dontask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The advantage of nearly all dynamic languages over C is that it's much harder to get buffer overflows while doing string manipulation, which can easily become a security problem.

Also Perl has libraries that help you dealing with the CGI protocol, and they are battle tested and stable.